# How can I divide two integers stored in variables in Python?

Tags: python

I've got two numbers stored in varibles, a and b, and i'd like to see of the ratio of those two is an integer or not in python.  However when I try

```
result = a./b
```

it gives me a

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

however if I say

```
result = a/b
```

it truncates the decimal portion.  How can I get the full numbeer to test for integrality?

I was going to use

```
if (not isinstance(result, (int, long))): 
    then do something for non-integer numbers..
```

Thanks, and i'm using python 2.7.1

Comment: As zephyr wrote below, use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).  This is exactly what it does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this line to get the division behavior you want:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Alternatively, you could use modulus:

```
if (a % b) == 0: #do something
```

Answer (score 14):

Multiply by 1.

```
result = 1. * a / b
```

or, using the float function

```
result = float(a) / b
```

Answer (score 11):

The `1./2` syntax works because `1.` is a float. It's the same as `1.0`. The dot isn't a special operator that makes something a float. So, you need to either turn one (or both) of the operands into floats some other way -- for example by using `float()` on them, or by changing however they were calculated to use floats -- or turn on "true division", by using `from __future__ import division` at the top of the module.

Answer (score 2):

```
x / y
```

quotient of x and y

```
x // y
```

(floored) quotient of x and y

Comment: except if `x` and `y` are integers, as is the case here.

Comment: @Thomas Wouters: In Python 3 (and Python 2 with `from __future__ import division`), it's always like that.

Comment: @delnan: yes, I'm aware. That's obviously not the case in the OP's question, or `a/b` wouldn't be truncating anything.

Answer (score -1):

if 'a' is already a decimal; adding '.' would make 3.4/b(for example) into 3.4./b

Try float(a)/b